# Unity Cloud Build link with Continuous Integration systems

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-delivery, unity3d-cloud-build

After a successful build in Unity Cloud Build I would like to send the generated .zip file url to a Continuous Integration system like Travis CI in order to to deploy that file into another server. To do this right now I need to call a custom webhook in my own server that checks (via API) the last build link and starts a Travis CI build via HTTP POST method.

What's the best approach to do this without needing my intermediate step? I'have tried to do this HTTP POST request inside the post-script method in Unity Cloud Build but this seems to be a bad workaround.

Comment: There's isn't really any other way to do it. Cloud Build doesn't have much deep integration with other systems at the moment. What I would suggest, if you have the time and patience, is Jenkins. There is a free Unity plugin developed by the community and Jenkins does the build and continuous integration all in one package so you don't really have to spread your pipeline over multiple platforms.

Comment: @BrandonMiller Thanks a lot for your time! Bad thing of Jenkins is that is not cloud hosted, and that's a really positive point in favour of Travis CI, unfortunately it seems I'll need to keep my webhook.

Comment: That's understandable. Heroku looks promising since it is cloud based, and offers both CI and Build operations, but I'm not sure about its integration with Unity.. Also, from my experience, Heroku can get very expensive very fast. The last option would be to use AWS CodeBuild and AWS CodePipeline, but again, I'm not sure how tightly AWS has been integrated with Unity.